# Proof that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^4(k)}{k^2}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question in my analysis course and am not sure about my solution. Firstly I would like to know if my solution is at all correct and/or written well. But as well, my solution doesn't seem particularly "nice", and I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about it (overall or for any specific step I have taken)?

Also note the only theorems we have learned for determining the convergence of series so far is the comparison test and the theorem that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ is convergent iff $\alpha > 1$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. So if there is a better solution using other results I would love to know but my solution would need to only use the results I mentioned.

**Question**

Determine whether the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^4(k)}{k^2}$$
is convergent.

**My solution**

Firstly
$$\frac{\log^4(k)}{k^2}=\frac{1}{k^\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \frac{\log^4(k)}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{k^\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \left(\frac{\log(k)}{k^\frac{1}{8}}\right)^4$$

Now we know that by the "powers beat logs rule" that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(k)}{k^\frac{1}{8}} = 0$, and so by definition, choosing $\epsilon = 1$, there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \frac{\log(k)}{k^\frac{1}{8}} \leq 1$$
for all $k \geq n_0$ (can drop the absolute value as $\log(x)$ and $x^\frac{1}{8}$ are greater than zero for $x\in\mathbb{N}$).

Therefore we have, for $k \geq n_0$
$$\frac{\log^4(k)}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^\frac{3}{2}}$$
and so as we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^\frac{3}{2}}$ converges, by the comparison test we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^4(k)}{k^2}$ is also convergent.

Comment: Looks great and carefully written.

Comment: $\log k =5\log k^{1/5}<5k^{1/5}$.

Comment: The idea of writing $\log k$ as $n \log (k^{1/n})$ makes such problems very easy. It is worth remembering this.

Comment: Reference for the inequality used in the comment by @geetha290krm above https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/29/

Comment: Your solution seems very good.